# Removing last digit from a string containing numbers

Tags: ios, xcode, string

I simply need to remove the last digit from a string that contains numbers.

Say that my mutable string is named **scannedItem** and produces the following *038000768625*.

How can I remove the last digit, and put it into a new string that produces *03800076862*?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `new string` from old one. Firstly by `removing last character`

```
NSString *newString = [scannedItem substringToIndex:[scannedItem length]-1];
```

Now `append`

```
//Append string of your choice
newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
```